# Converting QString to std::string*

Tags: c++, qt

how can i do this:

---

```
_name__GetAvailable inp;

QString tmp;
inp.From = tmp;
```

---

this is definition of *name*_GetAvailable class:

```
class SOAP_CMAC _name__GetAvailable
{
public:
    std::string *From;  
    std::string *To;    
    struct soap *soap;  
}
```

I tried this :

```
inp.From = tmp.toStdString();
```

but i've got the following error:

> C:\Qt2\Qt5.0.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Ticket\mainwindow.cpp:49: error:
>   cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to
>   'std::string* {aka std::basic_string*}' in assignment

Comment: @sashoalm how is that a duplicate? If you read the question you'd see that he'd *already* converted from `QString` to `std::string`. His problem is getting a *pointer* to a `std::string`

Comment: @sashoalm OP wants a `std::string*` not just a `std::string`.

Comment: If you have a std::string, you should be able to come up with a pointer from it, or you should go back to learning C++.

Comment: true. (But that still doesn't make it a duplicate)

Comment: The duplicate is for anyone coming from a Google Search.

Comment: @sashoalm That is stretching the definition of "duplicate" somewhat. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a `std::string` pointer, you need to allocate a new `std::string` :

```
inp.From = new std::string(tmp.toStdString());
```

But I really don't see the reason why you would need to manipulate `std::string` by pointer.

If `OAP_CMAC _name__GetAvailable` is yours, you could manipulate `std::string` by value :

```
class SOAP_CMAC _name__GetAvailable
{
public:
    std::string From;  
    std::string To;    
    struct soap *soap;  
}
```

Otherwise, **don't forget to `delete`** the `std::string*` `From` and `To` at some point.

Comment: Thanks it worked
I used gSOAP toolkit for creating some header and source files
and now i'm using its class and functions and i cant change their definitions